# ¿Como hacer un redireccionamiento en joomla?

Tags: url, redirección, dns, joomla3, ip

necesito una ayuda URGENTE con el siguiente tema:
Resulta que nuestro sitio web este alojado con Godaddy y le cambiamos los DNS ya que estos estaban con otro proveedor. Y al hacer el cambio el contendió del sitio (que esta hecho en Joomla) no esta dentro de la carpeta /public_html sino que esta dentro de la carpeta /public_html/acrip.org (COMO MUESTRA LA IMAGEN)

El problema que tenemos es que cuando se ingresa a la url del sitio accede directamente a la carpeta acrip.org, que es donde se encuentra el Joomla y no a public_html

Soporte nos dice que se puede pasar el Joomla (que esta en acrip.org) a public_html, pero el tema es la base de datos de Joomla y la información se podría dañar, la mejor solución es hacer un redireccionamiento que cuando entre a la url acceda directamente a acrip.org (pasando por encima de public_html.

Buscando en internet encontré este link 
[link](http://www.comocreartuweb.com/herramientas-utiles/redireccionar-paginas/redireccionar-web-javascript.html). Pero no sé si sirva

¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo?

GRACIAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo porque se dañaría la base de datos. Por lo que entiendo hicieron una migracion de sitio web no?
Yo lo que hago es que solo saco el contenido (en este caso la carpeta acrip.org) y lo pongo a la altura public_html

Hasta donde tengo entendido Joomla y sus bases de datos solo se fijan en la URL absoluta

Comment: Gracias Víctor, en efecto se hizo una migración pero el sitio lo alojaron dentro de esa carpeta (acrip.org) y por buenas practicas (y el dns) debería esta en public_html. Lo que yo te entiendo es que si pasamos todo a la carpeta public_html los contenidos no se dañarian?. GRACIAS nuevamente

Comment: Pues yo lo he hecho tanto como en Joomla o Wordpress y no ha pasado nada. Al menos que tambien hayan cambiado de nombre de dominio.
Todas las rutas dinamicas de wordpress o Joomla las estableces en el menu general.

Podrias probar.... igual las buenas practicas dicen que hagas backup antes de hacer algo xD

Si no funciona solo lo restableces y listo

Comment: ok .. Gracias ... Investigando encontre este turorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSZ3N2zhjxk voy a mirar. GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Desde el hosting deberías poder hacer la redirección directamente sin usar joomla. Si usa CPanel es muy sencillo: Sección DOMINIOS - REDIRIGE